# d3 error from plotly: TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: d3.js, plotly

Trying to create my first chart with plotly and I am getting a d3 error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function d3.v3.min.js:1
    (anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:1
    e @ d3.v3.min.js:1
    (anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:3
    N @ d3.v3.min.js:1
    Ro.each @ d3.v3.min.js:3
    Ro.classed @ d3.v3.min.js:3
    I.plot @ plotly.min.js:11
```

Here is my actual code. Note that I am running this with the js that I downloaded from here: http://d14fo0winaifog.cloudfront.net/plotlyjs_basic.zip.

Could my problem be that I am trying to create a histogram2dcontour plot and that is not available in the the code I get from that link?

```
function generate_heatmap(divId) {
 var data = [
  {
    x: ["X", "-45470.884", "-25150.884", "-4830.884", "15489.116", "35809.116", "56129.116", "96769.116", "76449.116", "56129.116", "35809.116", "15489.116", "-4830.884", "-25150.884", "-45470.884", "-65790.884", "-86110.884", "-106430.884", "-86110.884", "-65790.884", "-45470.884", "-25150.884", "-4830.884", "15489.116", "35809.116", "56129.116", "76449.116", "96769.116", "117089.116", "137409.116", "117089.116", "96769.116", "76449.116", "56129.116", "35809.116", "15489.116", "-4830.884", "-25150.884", "-45470.884", "-65790.884", "-86110.884", "-106430.884", "-126750.884", "-126750.884", "-106430.884", "-86110.884", "-65790.884", "-45470.884", "-25150.884", "-4830.884", "15489.116", "35809.116", "56129.116", "76449.116", "96769.116", "117089.116", "137409.116", "137409.116", "117089.116", "96769.116", "76449.116", "56129.116", "35809.116", "15489.116", "-4830.884", "-25150.884", "-45470.884", "-65790.884", "-86110.884", "-106430.884", "-126750.884", "-106430.884", "-86110.884", "-65790.884", "-45470.884", "-25150.884", "-4830.884", "15489.116", "35809.116", "56129.116", "76449.116", "96769.116", "117089.116", "96769.116", "76449.116", "56129.116", "35809.116", "15489.116", "-4830.884", "-25150.884", "-45470.884", "-65790.884", "-86110.884", "-45470.884", "-25150.884", "-4830.884", "15489.116", "35809.116", "56129.116"], 
    y: ["Y", "126470.809", "126470.809", "126470.809", "126470.809", "126470.809", "126470.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "96030.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "65590.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "35150.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "4710.809", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-25729.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-56169.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-86609.191", "-117049.191", "-117049.191", "-117049.191", "-117049.191", "-117049.191", "-117049.191"], 
    z: ["Bottom", "2402.508", "2394.335", "2392.09", "2379.4", "2390.327", "2387.344", "2383.739", "2362.802", "2394.312", "2417.5", "2422.291", "2426.842", "2421.105", "2407.7", "2395.756", "2395.244", "2390.439", "2408.907", "2418.84", "2404.997", "2393.726", "2382.456", "2395.41", "2405.049", "2415.781", "2412.865", "2389.956", "2385.163", "2307.628", "2360.378", "2407.691", "2410.356", "2377.242", "2358.369", "2372.157", "2375.485", "2361.955", "2359.317", "2388.163", "2426.737", "2409.668", "2407.087", "2391.4", "2416.33", "2420.959", "2378.277", "2363.087", "2393.965", "2382.122", "2409.348", "2373.825", "2366.037", "2403.651", "2417.157", "2397.253", "2395.124", "2566.075", "2399.791", "2421.277", "2411.701", "2377.111", "2360.186", "2383.232", "2385.762", "2372.153", "2364.688", "2399.55", "2429.811", "2420.915", "2391.578", "2379.343", "2435.295", "2422.931", "2410.738", "2368.105", "2363.223", "2367.033", "2386.632", "2414.157", "2426.998", "2399.832", "2396.781", "2380.191", "2391.172", "2416.81", "2432.585", "2423.98", "2429.311", "2427.395", "2439.335", "2414.746", "2375.659", "2375.096", "2382.304", "2388.411", "2382.999", "2366.534", "2383.433"], 
    autobinx: true, 
    autobiny: true, 
    autocolorscale: false, 
    autocontour: false, 
    colorbar: {
      x: 0.960996325031, 
      y: 0.534862385321, 
      bgcolor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", 
      bordercolor: "#444", 
      borderwidth: 0, 
      exponentformat: "B", 
      len: 1, 
      lenmode: "fraction", 
      nticks: 0, 
      outlinecolor: "#444", 
      outlinewidth: 1, 
      showexponent: "all", 
      showticklabels: true, 
      thickness: 30, 
      thicknessmode: "pixels", 
      tickangle: "auto", 
      tickfont: {
        color: "#444", 
        family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
        size: 12
      }, 
      tickmode: "auto", 
      ticks: "", 
      title: "yo ", 
      titlefont: {
        color: "#444", 
        family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
        size: 12
      }, 
      titleside: "top"
    }, 
    colorscale: "Hot", 
    contours: {
      coloring: "fill", 
      end: 5.505, 
      showlines: true, 
      size: 0.5, 
      start: 0.5
    }, 
    histnorm: "", 
    line: {
      color: "#000", 
      dash: "solid", 
      smoothing: 1, 
      width: 0.5
    }, 
    name: "Col3", 
    opacity: 1, 
    reversescale: false, 
    showscale: true, 
    type: "histogram2dcontour", 
    uid: "80eb26", 
    xbins: {
      end: 200000, 
      size: 50000, 
      start: -200000
    }, 
    ybins: {
      end: 200000, 
      size: 50000, 
      start: -200000
    }, 
    zauto: false, 
    zmax: 6, 
    zmin: 0
  }
 ];
 var layout = {
  autosize: true, 
  dragmode: "zoom", 
  font: {
    color: "#444", 
    family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
    size: 12
  }, 
  height: 463, 
  hidesources: false, 
  hovermode: "x", 
  paper_bgcolor: "#fff", 
  plot_bgcolor: "#fff", 
  separators: ".,", 
  title: "hi", 
  titlefont: {
    color: "#444", 
    family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
    size: 17
  }, 
  width: 869, 
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true, 
    exponentformat: "B", 
    gridcolor: "#eee", 
    gridwidth: 1, 
    mirror: false, 
    nticks: 0, 
    range: [-175000, 175000], 
    showexponent: "all", 
    showgrid: true, 
    showline: false, 
    showticklabels: true, 
    tickangle: "auto", 
    tickcolor: "#444", 
    tickfont: {
      color: "#444", 
      family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
      size: 12
    }, 
    ticklen: 5, 
    tickmode: "auto", 
    ticks: "outside", 
    tickwidth: 1, 
    title: "blow", 
    titlefont: {
      color: "#444", 
      family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
      size: 14
    }, 
    type: "linear", 
    zeroline: true, 
    zerolinecolor: "#444", 
    zerolinewidth: 1
  }, 
  yaxis: {
    autorange: true, 
    exponentformat: "B", 
    gridcolor: "#eee", 
    gridwidth: 1, 
    mirror: false, 
    nticks: 0, 
    range: [-175000, 175000], 
    showexponent: "all", 
    showgrid: true, 
    showline: false, 
    showticklabels: true, 
    tickangle: "auto", 
    tickcolor: "#444", 
    tickfont: {
      color: "#444", 
      family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
      size: 12
    }, 
    ticklen: 5, 
    tickmode: "auto", 
    ticks: "outside", 
    tickwidth: 1, 
    title: "yo", 
    titlefont: {
      color: "#444", 
      family: "\"Open sans\", verdana, arial, sans-serif", 
      size: 14
    }, 
    type: "linear", 
    zeroline: true, 
    zerolinecolor: "#444", 
    zerolinewidth: 1
  }
 };
 Plotly.plot(divId, data, layout);
}
```

Another update to show how I call this. This function is the on click handler for an object:

```
function load_heatmap()
{
    var hm_id = 'heatmap1';
    var el_hm = $('<div />').attr('id', hm_id);
    generate_heatmap(el_hm);
}
```

generate_heatmap is shown above. It ends with

```
Plotly.plot(divId, data, layout);
```

I un-minified plotly.js and it's blowing up on line 441:

```
  437                 function _(t) {
  438                     var e = x(t);
  439                     return function(n, r) {
  440                         if (a = n.classList) return r ? a.add(t) : a.remove(t);
  441                         var a = n.getAttribute("class") || "";
  442                         r ? (e.lastIndex = 0, e.test(a) || n.setAttribute("class", y(a + " " + t))) : n.setAttribute      ("class", y(a.replace(e, " ")))
  443                     }
  444                 }
```

I set a breakpoint at 441 and from the debugger I see this:

```
   > n
   < [<div id=​"heatmap1">​</div>​]

   > n.getAttribute
   < undefined
```

Comment: The code is an exact cut and paste of the code here: `https://plot.ly/~llanopa/8/hi/?share_key=2SzItKpDP1N4D5PLHB1qYF` Let me know if you can view it there. If not I will post it here.

Comment: It works on the plotly site, but not on my system with the plotly and d3 libs I downloaded from the plotly site. Does it work on your system?

Comment: Larry, this example http://bl.ocks.org/etpinard/b74432ea2aa0e972e11b might help you out.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I need to programmatically generate charts in my app. My client made that example chart on your website and I just cut and pasted the code into my app to integrate it in and show proof of concept. Once I have that working then I will make it load data programmatically and add the other bells and whistles they want. Could my problem be that I am trying to create a histogram2dcontour plot and that is not available in the the code I get from the download js link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the plotly node.js [API](https://plot.ly/nodejs/) and [plotlyjs](https://plot.ly/javascript/).

Changing the `Plotly.plot` call signature to

`Plotly.plot(divId, data, layout)`

should make things work.

In your case, the `divId` is `hm_id`.

Note that the `.js` code tabs shows reproducible node.js code, not plotlyjs. Moreover, the free [basic plotlyjs](https://plot.ly/javascript/#basic-charts) does not feature the histogram 2d contour trace type.

Comment: I did not realize that the .js code tab did not show code that would work with plotlyjs. Is there any way I can use the code from that tab with plotIyjs? I made the change you suggested and I get the exact same error.

Comment: Yes, I have seen those docs. I now have the advanced lib that does support the histogram 2d contour trace type and I am getting the same error. The error is from d3, which is called by plotly. How can I debug that?

Comment: Could you copy/paste your HTML index as well?

Comment: I don't have an index.html. This is part of a very large django based app. The part of the app that I am trying to add plotly to is some jQuery code that is invoked when the user clicks on something. That jQuery code creates a div and then calls a js function to run that calls plotly. I have been debugging this and it seem to not like this div I pass in. I will update the original post with more code to show you.

Comment: Plotly.plot doesn't accept jQuery selections as its first argument. Pass in only the div id and things should work.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!!